# Testing a service - how to inject tested service only once

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

```
  it('should ...', inject([XService], (service: XService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

This way I can use service inside 'it'. There is a lot more 'it' and I don't want to inject service every time. I would like to inject the service once somewhere at the start (in beforeEach for example) but I can't. xService has a lot of dependencies inside constructor which I'd like to get also.

The only way I could've done this was to set all those values inside the first 'it'.

```
let xService: XService;
let yService: YService;
let zService: ZService;

beforeEach(() => ...);

  it('should ...', inject([XService], (service: XService) => {
    xService = service;
    yService = xService['yService'];
    zService = xService['zService'];

    expect(xService).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

But personally I thinks this is an ugly solution. Can I in some way move it to beforeEach?

Comment: It depends if you want all yours tests to have the service injected or not.

Check out the official documentation, you could manage to inject your service from the root injector instead of the component injector, thus injecting it from a beforeEach for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `inject`, try using `TestBed.get()`. It's basically the same functionality, and your problem can be solved with it easily:

```
let xService: XService;
let yService: YService;
let zService: ZService;

beforeEach( () => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule( ... ).compileComponents();

    xService = TestBed.get( XService );
    yService = TestBed.get( YService );
    zService = TestBed.get( ZService );

} );

it( 'should ...',() => {

    expect( xService instanceof XService ).toBe( true );

} );
```